# Can SSO be used by AD users when using my externally hosted website developed for those users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory, single-sign-on

I am developing a web site for an organization that used AD for validating its own employees. I am required to host the web site externally. The organization requires a Single Sign On for its employees. Can this be done? I am using Nodejs and javascript.

Comment: Look at OpenId Connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! (kind of)

Do you know if the org is using Azure AD or an on-prem AD?

If its Azure AD then you should be good to go, MS has some docs on how to do this and boilerplate code for it so I would suggest taking a look at those

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

The basic flow would be

- Setup an adapp in Azure (this would be on the Org to setup for you)
- Provide them with a 'return URL' (this will post back to you app with a JWT Token)
- Once setup, they will provide you wish a client key / secret
- Use those to pass to the AD auth service, this should prompt users to authenticate with Azure AD
- After Auth, it passes back to your 'return URL' with the token
- In your app, if the token is valid then they are authenticated and get access, if not, no access

Comment: @proximo Thank you very much. So if the Org is using on-prem AD then it cannot be done? Also wanted to know why you said 'kind of'?

Comment: @alokofaarmax so kind of, is because you need to use azure AD, outside of that you would need to have some kind of proxy service built to connect onto their AD. In the past, pre azure AD we had kind of an AD Bridge (old soap service) that we could ping against, and get back an Auth data so you probably will need to look at directly connecting to their public AD, its just gets tricky depending on where its located, is it internal only etc. Then again if its already exposed then you should be able to tap into it, but the future of AD is Azure AD, not that they are going to change that :D

Comment: @proximo. Thanks. Though I do not understand completely because of my lack of knowledge/expertise in this field. Thanks again.

Comment: @alokofaarmax essentially, if their AD is on-prem you need a way to access it, AD does have an API to connect to it, so you would just have to make sure its accessible  and make the necessary calls to authenticate against.